# Yii2 rbac user can not update his own post

Tags: php, yii2

So, i created permissions and roles than on register every user gets "user" role.
When the user tries to update someone else post he can not and that is ok. The problem is that he can not update even his posts. Can not figure it out. (All this works proper when i replace "user" with "@" in the controller)

```
public function up()
{
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

    //creating post
    $createPost = $auth->createPermission('createPost');
    $createPost->description = 'Create Post';
    $auth->add($createPost);

    //deleting post
    $deletePost = $auth->createPermission('deletePost');
    $deletePost->description = 'Delete Post';
    $auth->add($deletePost);

    //update post
    $updatePost = $auth->createPermission('updatePost');
    $updatePost->description = 'Update Post';
    $auth->add($updatePost);

    //delete user
    $deleteUser = $auth->createPermission('deleteUser');
    $deleteUser->description = 'Delete User';
    $auth->add($deleteUser);

    //create role 'user' and add permissions
    $user = $auth->createRole('user');
    $user->description = 'User';
    $auth->add($user);
    $auth->addChild($user, $createPost);
    $auth->addChild($user, $deletePost);
    $auth->addChild($user, $updatePost);

    //create role 'admin' and add permissions
    $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
    $admin->description = 'Administrator';
    $auth->add($admin);
    $auth->addChild($admin, $user);
    $auth->addChild($admin, $deleteUser);
}

public function down()
{
    Yii::$app->authManager->removeAll();
}
```

AuthorAccessRule(found it on stackoverflow):

```
class AuthorAccessRule extends AccessRule
{
    public $allow = true;
    public $roles = ['@'];

    public function allows($action, $user, $request)
    {
        $parentRules = parent::allows($action, $user, $request);
        // $parentRes can be `null`, `false` or `true`.
        // True means the parent rule matched and allows access.
        if($parentRules != true)
        {
            return $parentRules;
        }

        return ($this->getProjectAuthorId($request) == $user->id);
    }

    private function getProjectAuthorId($request)
    {
        // Fill in code to receive the right project.
        // assuming the project id is given à la `project/update?id=1
        $postId = $request->get('id');
        $post = Post::findOne($postId);
        return isset($post) ? $post->user_id : null;
    }
}
```

and the controller:

```
'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['update', 'delete'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['delete', 'update'],
                    'roles' => ['user'],
                    'class' => 'app\filters\AuthorAccessRule'
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['delete', 'update'],
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                ],
```

Comment: Did you correct assign 'user' role to concrete user ID? Try to debug does your function `getProjectAuthorId` return proper Id..

Comment: It can not pass through the parent::allows method. Will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug in which condition parent::allow does not pass. Yo can do it by eg:

```
public function allows($action, $user, $request)
{
    $a = $this->matchAction($action);
    $b = $this->matchRole($user);
    $c = $this->matchIP($request->getUserIP());
    $d = $this->matchVerb($request->getMethod());
    $e = $this->matchController($action->controller);
    $f = $this->matchCustom($action);
    $g = $this->allow;

    throw new \Exception("$a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g");

    $parentRules = parent::allows($action, $user, $request);
    // $parentRes can be `null`, `false` or `true`.
    // True means the parent rule matched and allows access.
    if($parentRules != true)
    {
        return $parentRules;
    }
    return ($this->getProjectAuthorId($request) == $user->id);
}
```

Check in witch case is 0 in exception message?

Comment: Seems like the problem is in $b, the user role. It gave me false. Maybe i did not create the role right.

Comment: You should assign role to concrete user ID. Eg. `Yii::$app->authManager->assign($userRole, $userID);`

Comment: Yes i did that at the end of public `function up(){ ... $auth->assign($admin, 40);}` and on registration action i am adding user role to every new user like this `$role = \Yii::$app->authManager->getRole('user'); \Yii::$app->authManager->assign($role, $user->getId());`. Doing that after `user->save()`. I tried to do it before `user-save()` but user was not saving to the database. I am really thankful for your help!

Comment: But i am not sure if this `getRole('user')` is the right way.

Comment: Before run `user-save()`, user ID was null and so role could not be assigned to null ID.

Comment: At the end my conclusion as a newbie is that the roles did not even add when i use `$auth->add()`. No user role was added to the new users neither admin to the user with ID = 40.